# Export a list of addresses associated to blockchain.info account

Tags: blockchain.info

Is there any straightforward way to export just a list of my addresses I have in *Receive money* tab?
I would like to easily extract them to keep on the side to occasionally run `curl` on those addresses to get all unspent outputs for each without going to blockchain.info website and logging in.
I can do a copy-paste and `grep` whole content for addresses but maybe there is some more reliable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the blockchain.info wallet api to get a list of all of your addresses and their balances.  The "Listing Address" endpoint is what you're looking for if you go that route, which is very easily curlable.

```
https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/list?password=$main_password
```

It won't show archived or deleted addresses, but if you actually have a balance on those addresses you probably wouldn't archive them anyway.

[Blockchain.info Wallet API Documentation](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api)

You can also export your addresses from the wallet interface by going to the Account Settings > Import/Export > Export Unencrypted.  All of your active addresses are in the big JSON document there.

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity that none of both provides same security level as copy-paste-grep as they are opening your account new vulnerabilities. Will open a FR in their repo.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem.
There is a neat trick to only copy a column in firefox http://www.alvinpoh.com/how-to-select-columns-of-text-in-your-browser-firefox/ (Just need to use Ctrl key) . For chrome install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/columncopy/lapbbfoohlcmlbdaakldmmallcbcbpjb?hl=en

Goto Receive Money Tab and in the list use Ctrl with mouse to select first coloumn and voila you have a list of addresses.